# best magento htaccess for performance

Tags: performance, htaccess, memory, gzip

we have installed several extensions and bits and pieces of code to optimize Magento htaccess. Now I see the code has gotte quite long and I am not sure this is all conflicting or supporting ...

So this is what we have so far. What are the best settings?

```
############################################
## http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/allowed_memory_size_exhausted  
## Increase memory limit according to Magento
php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## enable resulting html compression of php output
php_flag zlib.output_compression on

############################################
## enable apache served files compression (not php, html/images/css/js
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filter on all content
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

############################################
## Enable keep-alives to reduce # http requests
## http://yoast.com/magento-performance-hosting/

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
</IfModule>
```

and as I understand the **next improvement** is moving all these rules in htaccess to the virtualhost configuration directives mentioned here:

http://markshust.com/2012/01/11/removing-htaccess-files-magento-and-moving-contents-apache-configuration

Comment: No .htaccess is the best .htaccess for performance. =D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[You could increase the `memory_limit` to the minimum recommended 256MB](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements). Outside of that, there's no real performance improvement to be gained in editing your htaccess.

The best htaccess is **not having one at all**. Move and/or rewrite your rules into your vhost definition in Apache and disable overrides.

> For highest performance use AllowOverride None everywhere in your
>   filesystem.

*Source*: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html#htaccess

Comment: And some benchmarking: http://www.eschrade.com/page/why-you-should-not-use-htaccess-allowoverride-all-in-production/

Comment: Is there a sample code for virtualhost, when using AllowOverride None

Comment: And when you do this, make sure you include all the protective .htaccess files in media/, var/, et.al. that deny casual access to all application areas. Don't want to fix performance only to destroy security. And Magento has them scattered all through the file system. Also of note for users of nginx, iis and other alternative web servers, .htaccess function must be duplicated for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The best .htaccess is no .htaccess. That means migrating all the .htaccess rules into your Apache (or other flavour of Web server) configuration.

One really good way to do this is to search for all .htaccess files in the Magento root and subfolders, combine these into one correctly formatted file and include this in your Apache config :

```
# Include combined Magento .htaccess files
<Directory /your_magento_root_here>
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
Include /your_magento_root_here/.htaccess-combined
```

More information as to how to achieve this and a script you can use to create the combined .htaccess can be found here:

http://colin.mollenhour.com/2010/06/30/the-right-way-to-optimize-apaches-htaccess-files/

Whenever you upgrade Magento, run the script again and restart your web server to pick up any changes in .htaccess rules.

Comment: Link is probably dead. How much difference does that migration make?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento comes with a .htaccess file that you can use for your installation. However, this .htaccess file is not optimized and misses a lot of things that can help your site. Therefor, we have created a .htaccess file for Magento that focusses on site speed, security and SEO. You can copy and paste it to use it as your own .htaccess file on your server.

```
######################################################################### 
################## Coding Basics Magento .htaccess File #################
# More Info: http://codingbasics.net/magento-htaccess-file-optimized-speed-security-seo/ #
######################################################################### 

##### Block unwanted Crawler Bots that clog your server #####

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 80legs [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]

##### Add support for SVG Images and CSS3 Pie #####

    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip svgz
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    DirectoryIndex index.php 

##### PHP Settings for your domain #####

<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    php_value memory_limit 512M 
    php_value max_execution_time 18000 
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off 
    php_flag session.auto_start off 
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off 
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off 
</IfModule>

##### Search Engine redirects and rewrites for SEO purposes #####

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Redirect away from /index.php and /home   
    ##### Warning: This index.php rewrite will prevent Magento 
    ##### Connect from working. Simply comment out the  
    ##### following two lines of code when using Connect.
    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://
    redirect 301 /home http://www.yourdomain.com

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>


##### mod_deflate compresses your output to lower the file size being sent to the client #####

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    php_flag zlib.output_compression on
</IfModule>

<Files *.php>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
</Files>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars 
</IfModule>


##### Header Directives #####

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>


##### disable POST processing to prevent breaking image upload #####

<IfModule mod_security.c> 
    SecFilterEngine Off 
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule> 


##### Served files compression on Apache for improved site speed #####

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>


##### Improve site speed through Mod gzip and caching #####

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.* 
</ifModule>


##### Default expires headers for all file types  #####
##### Not recommended for development environment #####

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule> 


##### Mime Type Caching Magento #####

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    ##### AUDIO #####
    AddType audio/mp4 m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg oga ogg

    ##### JAVASCRIPT #####
    # Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways):
    # http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    AddType application/javascript                      js jsonp
    AddType application/json                            json

    ##### VIDEO #####
    AddType video/mp4                                   mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

    ##### WEB FONTS #####
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    ##### Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types   #####
    ##### and sniff the content, however, Chrome shows  #####
    ##### a warning if other MIME types are used for    #####
    ##### the following fonts.                          #####
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf


    ##### OTHER #####
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash               swf
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType image/x-icon                                ico
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc
    AddType text/x-vcard                                vcf

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .webapp .xml
</IfModule>


##### Disable ETags http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags #####

    FileETag None


##### Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides #####

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


##### Force IE8 compatibility when using IE8+         #####
##### May cause issues within Windows Mobile Browsers ##### 

    BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
    Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support


##### By default allow all access #####

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
```

[source](http://codingbasics.net/magento-htaccess-file-optimized-speed-security-seo/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my blog in .htaccess file in Magento.
http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/magento-speed-optimization-htaccess/

Hope this will help.